# PHP: MDB2 error - call to undefined function

Tags: php, composer-php, pear, mdb2

I have error in my old project based od MDB2 and PHP 5.4:

**PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function: MDB2_Driver_pgsql::raiseError(). in /path/to/project/vendor/pear-pear.php.net/MDB2/MDB2.php on line 1936**

Dependencies loaded via composer:

```
"require": {
    "pear-pear.php.net/Validate": "0.7.0",
    "pear-pear.php.net/Validate_PL": "0.5.1",
    "pear-pear.php.net/HTML_Quickform": "*",
    "pear-pear.php.net/HTML_Table": "*",
    "pear-pear.php.net/MDB2": "*",
    "pear-pear.php.net/MDB2_Driver_pgsql": "*",
    "pear-pear.php.net/OLE": "1.0.0RC1",
    "pear-pear.php.net/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer": "0.9.1",
    "pear-pear.php.net/File_SearchReplace": "*",
```

And I don't change anything in this code. Anyone had this problem? :)

Comment: which PEAR version are you using?

Comment: PEAR in version 1.10.0

Comment: try to downgrad to pear 1.9.5

Answer (score 2):

This error is solved by installing PEAR-1.9.5

I've spent some time to find easy way to downgrade PEAR version.
It's easy to do by running terminal command:

```
pear install -f PEAR-1.9.5
```

Hope this will help someone to save extra time.